# Morris.Donut graph disappears after calling setData()

Tags: morris.js

I try to update Morris.Donut graph by calling setData() on it. But after the setData() method gets   executed, the graph disappears. I have searched on the web but found no solution to my problem.

What I have done here is:

```
    1) Initialize a Morris.Donut object
    2) Make a button. When I click on the button, I will update the graph with new data.
```

When I run my code, the graph gets shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeQVd.png). But after having clicked on the button to update the graph, the graph disappers.

My code

```
<div id="donut-chart" style="height: 200px;" data-width="100"></div>
<button type='button' class='update-chart'>Update chart</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Initialize a Morris.Donut object
        donut_chart = Morris.Donut({
            element: 'donut-chart',
            data: [
                {'label': 'Yes', 'value': 1},
                {'label': 'No', 'value': 0},
            ]
        });

        // Update the Morris.Donut object
        $('.update-chart').on('click', function(){
            line = {
                element: 'donut-chart',
                data: [
                    {'label': 'Yes', 'value': 2},
                    {'label': 'No', 'value': 0},
                ],
            };

            donut_chart.setData(line);  // This code makes the graph disapears
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write `donut_chart.setData(line.data);`

You do not need to pass the element with setData.

Comment: Hi Pierre. Thank you for your time. Your solution works perfect. It solves my problem.